# JQuery Validate user input text field

Tags: jquery

I have a text field that i want to validate with jquery. I want to allow user to input letters, numbers, spaces, question marks, points, comma, question mark, slashes, hyphens, quotation marks, and some basic characters when u write like a text description.

Thanx

Comment: Have a field day http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Where is your current code? StackOverflow isn't a *we'll write your code for you!* website.

Comment: what are the characters you want disallow from the text field?

Comment: I was just asking if there is like a pre defined  RegExpresion for it, i didnt ask no one to write the code for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple google search on this would take you to http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Here is a example:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
      <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
      <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
      <input id="curl" type="url" name="url"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
      <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
   $("#commentForm").validate();
</script>
```

Read the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation) for more info.